# How do I stack several columns while preserving the order of the rows in each?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have several short columns in Google Sheets that I'd like to combine into one column while maintaining the order of the rows in each.

For example, I have these:

COLUMN 1:

```
Spongebob
Pineapple
Jellyfishing
```

COLUMN 2:

```
Patrick Star
A Rock
Hanging with Spongebob
```

And I want this:

COLUMN 1

```
Spongebob
Pineapple
Jellyfishing
Patrick Star
A rock
Hanging with Spongebob
```

I've been playing around with `=unique({A:A;B:B})` but that gives me:

```
Spongebob
Patrick
Pineapple
A Rock
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure? Copying `=unique({A:A;B:B})` into a sheet provides me the results you're looking for...

Comment: I'm hoping for a column with rows A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 stacked in that order, but I end up with A1 B1 A2 B2 if I put that in

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However, when I do this it gives me the exact results you're looking for: https://imgur.com/KMmbAeT

Comment: @hmiedema9 Your solution appears include a blank line. How would you get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

```
={A1:A3;B1:B3}
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY({A1:A;B1:B},"where Col1<>''")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=FILTER({A:A;B:B},{A:A;B:B}<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({A:A;B:B}),"where Col1<>''")
```

[image: 0]